# Determine if a dll is being called by multiple threads from an application - Use ThreadId?

Tags: c++, dll

I have created a static dll file to be used by a certain application. I wanted to know if the exported methods of that dll are being called by separate threads of that application or by a single thread. I am thinking that if I output the threadid of the thread that calls a method in the dll this might help me figure out if the function is being called by a single thread or multiple threads. Will this help ? Also how will I get the threadid of the thread that is calling the dll ?

Comment: Why not try it and then come back when you have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GetCurrentThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
std::vector<DWORD> ids;

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall SomeFunction()
{
    DWORD id = GetCurrentThreadID();
    if (std::find(ids.begin(), ids.end(), id) != ids.end())
    {
        // New thread uses this function
        ids.push_back(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably more appropriate as a comment

Comment: I had an impression, that the whole question is, 'How can I get a thread ID'